# Не находит классы при компиляции через cmd

Tags: java, cmd, компиляция

При компиляции выдает ошибки error: cannot find symbol, хотя все лежит в одном месте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`javac -cp . Bellsprout.java` тоже не работает

Как донести до него, где эти классы?

Comment: Вместо картинки приведите текст ошибки в вопросе

Comment: `javac -cp . Bellsprout.java` выдаёт точно такие же ошибки или теряет другие классы?

Comment: Ошибки те же самые

Answer (score 1):

После удаления во всех классах строки объявления пакета и такой команды: `javac -sourcepath . -cp <нужный jar-архив> *.java` скомпилировалось